# Bash Formatting Output in Hex Bytes

Tags: bash

Suppose I have a output in stdout like this:

```
e28f6001
e12fff16
2210
4679
df01
6c656873
```

How can I pipe this in bash so I can append `\x` for each byte. I want the the output like this:

```
\xe2\x8f\x60\x01\xe1\x2f\xff\x16\x22\x10 ...
```

Comment: `sed -e 's/../\\x&/g'` though that won't join the lines.

Comment: As usual, what have you tried ?

Comment: `sed -r 's/([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/\\x\1/g' file | tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Seriously, show a little effort please. `tr -d '\n '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tr -d '\n' < File | sed 's/.\{2\}/\\x&/g'
```

Remove newline first. Then substitute every 2 characters (`.\{2\}`) with `\x` followed by the 2 characters (`&` => the matched pattern which will be those 2 characters).

Comment: You probably picked up the downvote when your answer (which you have since edited within the 5 minute window) consisted of a single line of code with no explanation.